# How to open file using vscode:// link

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use vscode ide link like phpstorm.

I know we can `phpstorm://open?file=@filepath&line=@line`

How can I achieve the same effect using vscode?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This link:

```
vscode://file/@file:@line
```

works.

---

Example: if you would like to open line 10 of `/path/to/file.txt` then the link will be:

```
vscode://file/path/to/file.txt:10
```