# HTML link starting with "vscode:" to open a file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: html, hyperlink, visual-studio-code

According to issue [#4883](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4883) and PR [#15320](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/15320) you can create `vscode:/` links in your HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<h1>Test</h1>
<a href="vscode://path/to/my/file.md">open file.md in vscode</a> 

</body>
</html>
```

This should have the same effect than typing following in the console:

```
code -g -r /path/to/my/file.md
```

But what I get is different:

[image: Example page]

After click:

[image: Example page after click]

And after clicking on "Open Visual Studio Code", then the application is opened (or put in the foreground) but the file is not opened.

What did I miss?

I have tried `<a href="vscode:///path/to/my/file.md">` but the result is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54459820/91497): you need a `file/` prefix before the path of your file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<h1>Test</h1>
<a href="vscode://file/path/to/my/file.md">open file.md in vscode</a> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it looks like *file* should be preceded double slashes - *//file/*